# JIRA component and version notification

Tags: jira

Is it possible to get email notification when a project version or component is changed (i.e. modified/delete/created)? I'm using JIRA 3.13.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default, but there is a JIRA admin plugin at https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/43203 that does track similar changes (for JIRA 4.x)

~Matt